# Spring Integration CallBack Methods

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-integration

Reading the Spring Integration samples, came a doubt in my mind.

I have a small application that given a scenario, a result from an "Integration Flow" is necessary to update a "result" in a "future".

Reading the MathServiceGateway sample didn't clarified  too much.

Does anyone have a suggestion for a "call back" like functions, the Channel Interceptor seems to be a next promise, but an async computation fits better on the scenario for "requests-response" (WebClient - Service - Spring Integration - Get Response) like the caller remains on hold until the Integration Flow finishes.

The Idea is to retrieve a result from a computation executed inside the Spring Integration.

Regards.

Answer (score 1):

Please, see the [Reference Manual](http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/latest-ga/reference/html/messaging-endpoints-chapter.html#async-gateway) on the matter.

You don't need to worry about any `callback` or some manual setting to the `Future<?>`. According to the Spring Integration Gateway component logic everything is done for you by Framework.